# Number of images in each classes

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

Currently, I am training a model for image detection, and I want to know how many images do I need per class, do i need to have the same numbers of each object.

Please i need some advice.

I use Tensorflow, and Yolo v2 model.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need as many as you can get, but definitely in the order of tens of thousands at least if you're training the network from scratch (there are pre-trained weights for YOLOv2 trained on 
 - http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/).

It's best to have balanced classes, meaning the number of images for each class must be close, it's easier to train this way.

Why are you training the network yourself? Can't you use some pre-trained models, drop the FC layers and insert your own classes? This way it's much faster, and you don't need that many images.

Comment: Because the model that exist does't not recognise cartoon images, that why I need some adve to how concept correctly my dataset, and I want to say that I use a model who is training on object detection which is called YOLO 9000

Comment: You can use the pre-trained convolutional layers (http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/). The classification in those pre-trained models is done in the last fully-connected layers, but the convolutional layers are there to extract abstract features. You can drop the fully connected layers at the end, and add a couple of un-trained fully connected layers connected to the output of the convolutional layers.

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v542/n7639/full/nature21056.html . These guys used a pre-trained InceptionV3 model (trained on all kind of 1.3M images), hooked up their FC layers, and applied those to classify moles into malign and benign. The network did pretty well :)